# How Can i pass a additional value with TypeScript type constraint

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a generic class like this but i want to pass additional value with T

```
@Injectable()
export class Repository<T,// value //> {
   constructor(){
     let _value = value;
   }
}
```

-usage-

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private repo: Repository<Product, //string or numeric value//>) {
  }
```

i want to implement something like this, how can i pass the string or numeric value with generic parameter in typescript.

Comment: Not clear about what you are asking for. `Repository<T, Y extends string>`?

Comment: Hi @unional I want to pass numeric or string value to generic class. something like GUID, other-then the type constraint. Above type constraint is a Product class. and the second parameter is GUID.

if i use Repository<T, Y extends string> how can i get the Y value ?

Comment: You cannot pass "value" on "type". Can you give an explicit example on what do you want to "pass in"?

Comment: Hi @unional  something like this,  
export class Repository<T> { constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { this.itemsRef = db.list('products');} . i dont want to hardcode 'products' inside the genaric class i want to pass it from the calling class.

Comment: @unional is it possible to implement something like that ?

Comment: Just pass the value through constructor/method call

Answer (score 0):

Generic types are satisfied with type arguments, rather than literal values (although you can do some very funky stuff with it - but in your case you don't need to).

You can accept a `listType` and limit it to `string`, or to a string literal type, as I have shown below (it looks like a union type, but has string values as it's type members).

```
class Repository<T> {
  private itemsRef: T[];

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, listType: 'products' | 'customers') {
    this.itemsRef = db.list(listType);
  }
}
```

The fragile part of this is that a consumer could pass an incompatible `T` and `listType` - so you might want to create a `RepositioryFactory` to prevent this.

## Factory Variation

Here is the version with a factory method, which prevents the incompatibility error.

```
type ListType = 'products' | 'customers';

class Repository<T> {
  private itemsRef: T[];

  protected constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, listType: ListType) {
    this.itemsRef = db.list(listType);
  }

  static getInstance(db: AngularFireDatabase, listType: 'products'): Repository<Product>;
  static getInstance(db: AngularFireDatabase, listType: 'customers'): Repository<Customer>;
  static getInstance(db: AngularFireDatabase, listType: ListType) {
    switch (listType) {
      case 'products':
        return new Repository<Product>(db, listType);
      case 'customers':
        return new Repository<Customer>(db, listType);
      default:
        throw new Error(`No Respository<T> for ${listType}`);
    }
  }
}
```